# Python subprocess: pipe into script without breaking the started program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python program that starts an interactive program like Vim using `subprocess.run`.

It works fine, but piping into it breaks the started program:

`Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`

My python program does care about `stdin`, but the started program should not ; it should not receive anything.

Some people seem to close `sys.stdin` and re-open it to `/dev/tty`, but it does not work for me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you show your full  `subprocess.run()` call? it has special argument `input`

Comment: It's very simple: `run([self.editor, file.name], check=True)`. Do note that I'm trying to have it ignore the input and simply start on the original tty.

Comment: "does not work for me" -- that's firstly not a problem description (observations, not interpretations!) but it also means that you must be doing mistakes copying others' working code.

Comment: @ulrich-eckhardt Thank you for your reply. I have no doubt I must be doing something wrong regarding closing and re-setting sys.stdin to /dev/tty, especially considering I had gotten it to work a long time ago, but it is also intended as an extra mention, as my problem mainly lies in my understanding of the spawning process. I could re-set sys.stdin, but would still remain unsure of the legality of it. My code currently does `sys.stdin.close()` followed by `sys.stdin = os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_RDONLY)`.